# process control block vs process descriptor

Tags: process, linux-kernel

what is the exact difference between `process control block` and `process descriptor`?.

I was reading about kernel of linux. It was written that there is some `thread_info` structure which contains the pointer to actual process descriptor table. It was written that the `thread_info`  lies  just above/below of kernel stack. So definitely `thread_info` is in main memory. But what about actual process descriptor `task_struct`? where is it located? If process descriptor resides in main memory, where is the actual place for it ?

Answer (score 3):

The [`thread_info`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/+code=thread_info) and [`task_struct`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/sched.h#L1182) structures are just two different structures that hold different pieces of information about a thread, with the `thread_info` holding more architecture-specific data than the `task_struct`.  It makes more sense to split up the information rather than keep it all in the same structure.  (Although you could put them in the same struct; the 2.4 Linux kernel did this.)

How those structs are allocated depends on the architecture you're using.  The relevant functions you want to examine are [`alloc_task_struct()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/+code=alloc_task_struct) and [`alloc_thread_info()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/+code=alloc_thread_info).

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel, the process descriptor is a structure called task_struct, which keeps track of process attributes and information. All kernel information regarding a process is found there.